# Can't establish connection to UR5 using ROS-Industrial driver

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-industrial, rosrun, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently running on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and UR Software 3.3.0.145. I have gone through the ROS tutorial for installing Indigo and setting up my catkin workspace. Next I cloned the the github repo for the `ur_modern_driver` into `catkin_ws/src` and made it with `catkin_make`. From there I have tried to follow the universal robot getting started with ROS Industrial tutorial...

[Universal Robot ROS Industrial Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial)

I can ping the UR5 and run my own python scripts with URScript commands so the communication appears to be in check.

My problem is with step 3.3 in the tutorial when I try to run

```
roslaunch ur_bringup ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=IP_OF_THE_ROBOT [reverse_port:=REVERSE_PORT]
```

and

```
rosrun ur_driver test_move.py
```

When I run the roslaunch command from the `~/catkin_ws` directory I get the error

```
[ur5_bringup.launch] is neither a launch file in package [ur_bringup] nor is [ur_bringup] a launch file name
```

However, I have been able to get it to launch once by switching to the `~/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/launch` directory and omitting `ur_bringup` at the start of the command, but the `rosrun` command would not do anything on the arm. Coming back after the weekend and trying to run the same thing I get an

```
Error connecting to get firmware version
```

So I appear to be back at square one trying to get `roslaunch` to work.

I'm not sure if this would be an issue, but the computer I am currently running from is not connected to the internet when I run commands because there is only one ethernet port which needs to be connected to the UR5. I have made sure to run `source devel/setup.bash` before the `roslaunch` command and have checked that the .launch files do in fact exist in the launch folder.

Any insight / ideas are greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Pawel

**[UPDATE]**

After trying the suggested line
`roslaunch ur_modern_driver ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=IP.OF.YOUR.UR`
I get the same sort of error as before with the `Error connecting to get firmware`. It appears that it is trying to use the UR3 driver for some reason? Once again I made sure to run `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` beforehand. I pasted the error below...

```
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4135]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to a2d5b39c-7a9d-11e6-b304-001cc0933a57
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4148]
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [4151]
process[ur_driver-3]: started with pid [4152]
[FATAL] [1473872815.699936438]: Error connecting to get firmware version
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Invalid argument
[ur_driver-3] process has died [pid 4152, exit code -6, cmd     /home/robots/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ur_modern_driver/ur_driver __name:=ur_driver     __log:=/home/robots/.ros/log/a2d5b39c-7a9d-11e6-b304-001cc0933a57/ur_driver-3.log].
log file: /home/robots/.ros/log/a2d5b39c-7a9d-11e6-b304-001cc0933a57/ur_driver-3*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243601/can%27t-establish-connection-to-ur5-using-ros-industrial-driver/) by [Pawel](https://answers.ros.org/users/27968/pawel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-12**:
May I suggest a topic title change? While you mention `test_move.py` in your question, the real issue seems to be with getting the launch file to start, and getting the driver to communicate with your controller. If that works, *then* I would start looking at `test_move.py`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-12**:
Note btw that the tutorial you linked is for the packages in `universal_robot` *only*. The `ur_modern_driver` is (currently still) a package separate from that repository. Copy/pasting the commands from the tutorial will not work, as you found out.

**Comment by [Pawel](https://answers.ros.org/users/27968/pawel/) on 2016-09-13**:
Thanks, I made the change to the title. I know that the tutorial was for universal_robot, but I remember that the ur_modern_driver git mentioned that it was meant to be a drop-in replacement. I thought that it should have worked the same in that case?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-13**:
It is a drop-in replacement, but not if you try to start a launch file from `ur_bringup`: those launch files will be using `ur_driver`, not `ur_modern_driver`. Hence my comment that you can't (just) copy/paste.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-13**:
It would perhaps be an idea to verify first that `ur_modern_driver` is compatible with Polyscope version 3.3.0.145: perhaps you could ask that on the `ur_modern_driver` github issue tracker?

**Comment by [Pawel](https://answers.ros.org/users/27968/pawel/) on 2016-09-13**:
Thanks for the idea, I'll get right on that!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-14**:\

> It appears that it is trying to use the UR3 driver

no, it's not. The filename of the log if just `ur_driver-3<and something>.log`. That has nothing to do with UR3s.

Besides: there is no such thing as a UR3 driver: the driver is arm agnostic, only the controller matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, If you want to use the `ur_modern_driver`, which you must if you're running PolyScope 3.X, you should use the launchfiles from that package. Instead of `roslaunch ur_bringup ur5...`. Try with

```
roslaunch ur_modern_driver ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=IP.OF.YOUR.UR
```

For testing, I'd say the `test_move.py` in `ur_driver` should work fine **once the driver is running** (i.e. do not kill the driver to run the next command, but do it in a new terminal instead). However, it might make your life easier if you try with the `test_move.py` script in the modern driver package with

```
rosrun ur_modern_driver test_move.py
```

On the second half of your question, you mention several issues (e.g. `roslaunch` failing to find `ur_bringup`, the error about failing to get the firmware version, stuff magically behaving differently after the weekend) which suggest you're not being careful enough when trying this. Please, try the two commands I typed for you above, in separate terminals, making sure to run `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` in **each terminal** before either the `roslaunch` or `rosrun` commands, and report back with any errors you encounter.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2016-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pawel](https://answers.ros.org/users/27968/pawel/) on 2016-09-14**:
Thanks for the quick reply! I tried that out and seem to be getting the same error. I made an update to the post with the error printout. It appears that it is trying to use the UR3 driver for some reason.